# C strtok is creating an invalid read of size 1 unable to free(token)

Tags: c, valgrind, free, strtok

Been trying to debug this simple c program:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_WORD_SIZE 60
int wordCnt = 0;

int main(void){

//open dictionary 
FILE *ptr = fopen("large", "r");
if(ptr == NULL){
  printf("unable to open %s","large");
}

//get file size 
int fileSize;
fseek(ptr, 0 , SEEK_END);
fileSize=ftell(ptr) ;

//get memory for file buffer (read in whole file at once, faster) 
char * buffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*fileSize);

//rewind and read in file
fseek(ptr, 0 , SEEK_SET);
fread(buffer, fileSize, 1, ptr);

//get memory for longest word
char * token = malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_WORD_SIZE);
```

//here's the part causing the problem

```
while (token != NULL)
{
    if(wordCnt == 0)token = strtok(buffer, "\r\n");
    else token = strtok(NULL, "\r\n");

    wordCnt++;
}
wordCnt--;    

fclose(ptr);
free(token);
free(buffer);
}
```

and here are the error messages from valgrind:

```
valgrind ./test
==16233== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==16233== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==16233== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==16233== Command: ./test
==16233== 
==16233== Invalid read of size 1
==16233==    at 0x5E4496C: strtok (strtok.S:137)
==16233==    by 0x42D848: main (test.c:43)
==16233==  Address 0x62dd8bc is 0 bytes after a block of size 1,439,228 alloc'd
==16233==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==16233==    by 0x42D728: main (test.c:29)
==16233== 
==16233== Invalid read of size 1
==16233==    at 0x5E4499C: strtok (strtok.S:163)
==16233==    by 0x42D848: main (test.c:43)
==16233==  Address 0x62dd8bc is 0 bytes after a block of size 1,439,228 alloc'd
==16233==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==16233==    by 0x42D728: main (test.c:29)
==16233== 
==16233== 
==16233== HEAP SUMMARY:
==16233==     in use at exit: 60 bytes in 1 blocks
==16233==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 2 frees, 1,439,856 bytes allocated
==16233== 
==16233== 60 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==16233==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==16233==    by 0x42D7B1: main (test.c:36)
==16233== 
==16233== LEAK SUMMARY:
==16233==    definitely lost: 60 bytes in 1 blocks
==16233==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16233==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16233==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16233==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16233== 
==16233== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==16233== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: `char * buffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*fileSize);` --> `char * buffer = malloc(fileSize +1);`

Comment: `fread(buffer, fileSize, 1, ptr);` --> `fread(buffer, fileSize, 1, ptr); buffer[fileSize]=0;`

Comment: `char * token = malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_WORD_SIZE);` --> `char * token=buffer;`//set dummy

Comment: `free(token);` : Delete this line.

Comment: that's awesome, thank you

Comment: By the way, your code (once working) is not counting words, but *lines*.

Comment: that's right but there's only 1 word per line

Answer (score 7):

The [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) function returns a pointer in the middle of the buffer you provide with the initial call, you should not call `free` with that pointer.

And the memory leak reported is because you allocate memory and make `token` ***initially*** point to that memory. Then in the tokenization loop you make `token` point to memory inside `buffer`.

A typical loop using [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) would be something like

```
char *token = strtok(buffer, "\r\n");
while (token != NULL)
{
    ++wordCnt;
    token = strtok(NULL, "\r\n");
}
```

---

Lets say that buffer contains the string `"Hello\nWorld"`.

In memory it looks something like

```
+--------+     +---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+---+---+---+----+
| buffer | --> | H | e | l | l | o | \n | W | o | r | l | d | \0 |
+--------+     +---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+---+---+---+----+
```

After you do

```
char *token = strtok(buffer, "\r\n");
```

Then you have something like

```
+--------+     +---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+---+---+---+----+
| buffer | --> | H | e | l | l | o | \n | W | o | r | l | d | \0 |
+--------+     +---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+---+---+---+----+
                                        ^
+-------+                               |
| token | ------------------------------/
+-------+
```

That is, `token` is pointing into to the location after the newline (the beginning of the "word" `"World"`), but it's inside of the memory allocated for `buffer`.

---

There's also another problem: The `strtok` function expects the string you tokenize to be an actual null terminated string. Yours isn't, and this is what is causing the "Invalid read" error as `strtok` goes out of bounds of the memory allocated for `buffer`.

You need to allocate one more byte for `buffer` and initialize the last byte to `'\0'` to make it terminated:

```
char * buffer = malloc(fileSize + 1);  // +1 for string terminator

// Read...

buffer[fileSize] = '\0';  // Terminate strings
```

<sub>Note that I don't multiply with `sizeof(char)` because it's defined in the specification to *always* be equal to `1`.</sub>

Comment: I don't understand.  I only allocate memory once to token and at the end I only free it once.

Comment: @DCR Please see my updated answer, hopefully it will make it clearer.

Comment: when I do  token = strtok(buffer,"\r\n") I get the first line in token null terminated.  On the subsequent calls I get each line in token null terminated even though buffer doesn't have any nulls (except possibly at the end)

Comment: @DCR After the first call to `strtok`, try to print out `buffer`. The `strtok` function *modifies* the buffer by replacing the found token with the terminator. You should read e.g. [this `strtok` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

As a follow up to [Some programmer dude's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude) explanation, you might ask why you can't free a string by passing free() a pointer to any part of it. Couldn't the free function just iterate to the start or end of the allocated block?

Well, malloc allocates data in blocks. Each block has a header which keeps track of the size of the allocation. To be able to free that block, each free() must be able to access the header, to flag it as free in some way, maybe by setting the length to 0, maybe by zeroing the whole header, it depends on the implementation.

The thing is, free() assumes the position of the header based on the pointer you pass to it. It can't just pick out the header from the rest of the data. It has to know where it is in relation to the pointer.

To demonstrate, let's make a pretend, trivial memory allocator.

```
typedef struct s_memory_block {
    int Size;
    char Memory[1];
} memory_block;

char *AllocateMemory(size_t Size)
{
    memory_block *Block;
    Block = SomeOperatingSystemMemoryAllocator(sizeof(int) + sizeof(char) * Size);
    Block->Size = Size;
    return &Block->Memory[0];
}

void FreeMemory(char *Memory)
{
    memory_block *Block;
    Block = Memory - sizeof(int); // assume the header is right in front of the pointer
    Block->Length = 0;
}
```

Obviously this is a stupid and trivial example but it might help you understand. Storing bookkeeping memory before the pointer you return can be very useful in all sorts of ways. Take for example Sean Barret's [stb.h stretchy buffers](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stretchy_buffer.h).

Comment: Why use `char Memory[1];`? This array only has one space.

Comment: C doesn't do boundary checking, so you can access memory past the boundary of the array by just indexing it Memory[2], Memory[3] etc. Because we allocated sizeof(char) * Size in the AllocateMemory routine, we have Size bytes of memory, but to access it we need to tell the compiler we're working with an array.
Why return char *? C has strange rules about what you can and can't cast from to try to prevent [point aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing). You would want to cast it to your desired type in the end.

Comment: NOTE: In any modern version of C you would want to use void *, not char *, but that's basically just a typedef'd version of char * that the compiler auto-casts.

Comment: But it is undefined behavior to even form an address, using pointer arithmetic, that is not in an array object, or one past the end of the array object, much less dereference the value stored there (C11 §6.5.2.1 2 and §6.5.6 8). It seems like you might want a flexible array member: `char Memory[]`.

Comment: @old_beginner but that is undefined behavior, to access past the boundary of an array. I don't know why you would want to do that.